# Unknown error getting products react-native-iap

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I have days trying to implement in app purchase in React Native without success. I was trying using In-app purchases from Expo and right now with ***react-native-iap*** and I'm facing this error:
***error code: E_UNKNOWN. error message: UNKNOWN_ERROR***

Subscription file

[image]

Apple Connect Info

[image]

App.tsx file:

[image]

Comment: How where you able to use rniap with expo? Do you need any special configuration?

Answer (score 4):

This bug occurs on ios Simulator, after hours and hours of search and no solutions, what you need to do is Running the app on real device.

connect ios device to your computer and run it on the real device and you will see your in-app products

[image: How it work]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test in app purchase in simulator.
There is way to test in app purchase in simulator
Using StoreKit we can test in app purchase in simulator please look at [this](https://www.appcoda.com/storekit-testing/)

Comment: this error occurred on real device iPhone13 pro max. any solution for this.